# dynamic content in angular, similar to append in jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using a rating in angular. But it happens that I want to create dynamically stars. append the function generated the code that should work the stars. But the stars are not shown I can do?

this is my code:
with this i want generate my content dynamic:

```
 angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic', 'ionic.rating'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myTitle = 'IONIC RATINGS DEMO';

  $scope.categories = [{
    name: "animals",
    question: "What do you think about the animals?",
    rating: 0
  }, {
    name: "cars",
    question: "What do you think about the cars?",
    rating: 0
  }, {
    name: "flowers",
    question: "What do you think about the flowers?",
    rating: 0
  }];

  $scope.rating = {};
  $scope.rating.max = 5;


$("#dynamic").append('<rating ng-model="categories[0].rating" max="rating.max"></rating>');


});

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/fraserxu/ionic-rating/master/ionic-rating.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/fraserxu/ionic-rating/master/ionic-rating.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <ion-view>
    <h1 class="text-center">{{myTitle}}</h1>
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item item-button-right" ng-repeat="category in categories">
        {{category.question}}
        <rating ng-model="category.rating" max="rating.max"></rating>
      </div>
    </div>

    <pre>categories = {{categories|json}}</pre>
  <div id='dynamic'></div>
  </ion-view>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to put the star corresponding to the first question.

```
categories[0].rating //first question
<div id='dynamic'></div> //in this div in my html
$("#dynamic").append('<rating ng-model="categories[0].rating" max="rating.max"></rating>');  //with .append I try...
```

.append using dynamic content but does not work.nothing appears. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```js
 angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic', 'ionic.rating'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myTitle = 'IONIC RATINGS DEMO';

  $scope.categories = [{
    name: "animals",
    question: "What do you think about the animals?",
    rating: 2
  }, {
    name: "cars",
    question: "What do you think about the cars?",
    rating: 0
  }, {
    name: "flowers",
    question: "What do you think about the flowers?",
    rating: 0
  }];

  $scope.rating = {};
  $scope.rating.max = 5;
   
$scope.$watch('categories[0].rating', function() {
 alert('New value: '+$scope.categories[0].rating);
}); 
   
 })
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/fraserxu/ionic-rating/master/ionic-rating.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/fraserxu/ionic-rating/master/ionic-rating.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <ion-view>
    <h1 class="text-center">{{myTitle}}</h1>
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item item-button-right" ng-repeat="category in categories">
        {{category.question}}
        <rating ng-model="category.rating" max="rating.max"></rating>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <pre>categories = {{categories|json}}</pre>
  <div id='dynamic'></div>
  </ion-view>
</body>

</html>
```